# CentOS 7: reinstalling python2.7 and yum

Tags: python-2.7, pip, centos7, setuptools, yum

I removed by mistake `/usr/lib64/libpython2.7.so`, and as a consequence, `yum` does not work.
So I'm trying to reinstall `python2.7.18` (which is the version that I currently have) from source, but in compilation I get that some modules are missing

```sh
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_bsddb             _curses            _curses_panel   
_ssl               _tkinter           bsddb185        
bz2                dl                 imageop         
readline           sunaudiodev                        
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.
```

But:
`yum` doesn't work, `pip2` also doesn't work, `setuptools` for `python setup.py install` is not found...
And all solutions I'm finding involve some of those, so I'm getting into some circular problem here.
I looked for the `*.rpm` for python 2.7.18 for CentOS 7, in the hope I could just install it with `rpm` and solve the issue, but I couldn't find it.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution, [starting from here](https://serverfault.com/questions/410075/reinstalling-python-on-centos-to-be-able-to-use-yum).

After manually `rm`-ing all the `/usr/**/*python2.7*` files (probably just the `libpython2.7.so*` and the python2.7 executables would be enough), from
`http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/`, I downloaded

```sh
bzip2-devel-1.0.6-13.el7.x86_64.rpm
compat-db-4.7.25-28.el7.x86_64.rpm
dlm-devel-4.0.7-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
dlm-lib-4.0.7-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
gdbm-1.10-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
gdbm-devel-1.10-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
keyutils-libs-devel-1.5.8-3.el7.x86_64.rpm
krb5-devel-1.15.1-46.el7.x86_64.rpm
libcom_err-devel-1.42.9-17.el7.x86_64.rpm
libdb-devel-5.3.21-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
libdb-tcl-5.3.21-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
libdb-tcl-devel-5.3.21-25.el7.x86_64.rpm
libselinux-devel-2.5-15.el7.x86_64.rpm
libsepol-devel-2.5-10.el7.x86_64.rpm
libverto-devel-0.2.5-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
ncurses-devel-5.9-14.20130511.el7_4.x86_64.rpm
openssl-devel-1.0.2k-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
pkgconfig-0.27.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-2.7.5-88.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-devel-2.7.5-88.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-libs-2.7.5-88.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-pycurl-7.19.0-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
sqlite-3.7.17-8.el7_7.1.x86_64.rpm
sqlite-devel-3.7.17-8.el7_7.1.x86_64.rpm
sqlite-tcl-3.7.17-8.el7_7.1.x86_64.rpm
python-setuptools-0.9.8-7.el7.noarch.rpm
python-six-1.9.0-2.el7.noarch.rpm
python-tools-2.7.5-88.el7.x86_64.rpm
python-urlgrabber-3.10-10.el7.noarch.rpm
readline-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
readline-devel-6.2-11.el7.x86_64.rpm
popt-devel-1.13-16.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-4.11.3-43.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-apidocs-4.11.3-43.el7.noarch.rpm
rpm-build-4.11.3-43.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-build-libs-4.11.3-43.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-devel-4.11.3-43.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpmdevtools-8.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm
rpm-libs-4.11.3-43.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm-python-4.11.3-43.el7.x86_64.rpm
sqlite-3.7.17-8.el7_7.1.x86_64.rpm
sqlite-devel-3.7.17-8.el7_7.1.x86_64.rpm
tcl-devel-8.5.13-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
tix-8.4.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
tix-devel-8.4.3-12.el7.x86_64.rpm
tk-devel-8.5.13-6.el7.x86_64.rpm
tkinter-2.7.5-88.el7.x86_64.rpm
yum-3.4.3-167.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
yum-metadata-parser-1.1.4-10.el7.x86_64.rpm
zlib-devel-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

and installed them with `sudo rpm -Uvh --replacepkgs --force *.rpm`.

Yum works fine now.